# Is it possible to create labels/entity types for a Custom Document Extractor using .NET client libraries?

Tags: .net, cloud-document-ai

I have successfully set up a Custom Document Extractor processor in the Google Cloud Console as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/workbench/build-custom-processor) and was able to familiarize myself with Google Document AI workflow. I was also able to create a Document Schema with custom labels and imported training and evaluation documents to train a Processor Version.

I was also able to set up the client libraries to programmatically interact with the processor using the latest .NET client library Google.Cloud.DocumentAI.V1Beta3 (2.0.0-beta03). I am able to train models and process docs. However, I need to be able to create labels using the client libraries as well, but I don't see whether this is possible using client libraries?

I went through the documentation [Google.Cloud.DocumentAI.V1Beta3 documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.DocumentAI.V1Beta3/latest) and [Document AI V1 Beta3 API reference documentation](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.documentai.v1beta3) I don't see any references to add your own labels using the client libraries. Are there any API requests that can be made to programmatically add labels using client libraries or gRPC/REST calls? Is this feature available or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's currently not supported to create/edit labels using the client libraries or REST/gRPC APIs.

If you have a Google Cloud Account Manager, I recommend reaching out to them to see about getting access to any Private Preview programs that may be available.